# Access instance variable from instance method in python

Tags: python-2.7, oop

```
                class SimpleBond(object):

                      def__init__(self,OriginationDate,SettleDate,Coupon,CouponFreq,Maturity,Par,StartingPrice = None):
                            self.CouponCFDaysFromOrigination = np.arange(1,self.NumCouponCFs + 1) * self.CashFlowDelta
                            self.OriginationCashFlowDates = np.array([self.StartDate + np.timedelta64(int(i),'D') for i in self.CouponCFDaysFromOrigination])
                            self.StartDate = OriginationDate

                      def GenerateCashFlowsAndDates(self):
                            CashFlowDates = self.OriginationCashFlowDates
                            self.CashFlowDates = CashFlowDates[(CashFlowDates >= self.SettleDate) & (CashFlowDates <=self.MaturityDate)]
```

I have a class definition as above. Some where else I instantiate the class as below:

```
BondObj = SimpleBond(OriginationDate = InceptionDate,SettleDate= np.datetime64('2008-02-15'),Coupon = 8.875,CouponFreq = 2,Maturity = 9.5,Par = 100.)
BondObj.GenerateCashFlowsAndDates()
```

The issue is with the call to `GenerateCashFlowDates()` as shown above, Once the BondObj is assigned to an instantiation of the SimpleBond class with the arguments to set the state.

When I step inside the call  `BondObj.GenerateCashFlowsAndDates()`....I can see the following state variables

`self.StartDate`.....its shows the actual state

where

`self.OriginationCashFlowDates` shows no value. It is `none`

As a matter of fact, all other instance variables that were set in the constructor are visible from `BondObj.GenerateCashFlowAndDates() call`

Many thanks

Comment: You didn't set any state there. You created a local variable called `CashFlowDates` which gets thrown away at the end of the method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have added more code to provide context and more (hopefully useful) comments so that I am more clear. Somehow the numpy array ( instance variable set inside the constructor) is not visible from the instance method where as other instance variables(set inside the constructor) are visible!!!

Comment: Actually, my stupidity is the reason why I was confused on this. There  was another assignment inside the constructor which was setting self.OriginationCashFlowDates to None which I couldn't see at the first look. Sorry, the code was handed over to me as a part of maintaining legacy code.

Comment: Thanks for your time Two-Bit. Sorry to have bothered with a dumb question

Comment: It happens. No big deal. Voting to close as "caused by a typo/unreproducible" :)